# meaning of ** within c++ class declarations

Tags: c++, class, syntax, member

I am confused by the usage of a double asterisk postpended to a class type in C++.

A paraphrase of the code I am reading would be

```
class ThisClass : protected SuperClass
{
  public:
    void MemberFunction(ThisClass** identifier);
}
```

I understand that `ThisClass* identifier`, with one asterisk, means that `identifier` is a pointer to an instance of `ThisClass`. 
Is `**` a repeated round of 'pointing', or has an altogether different meaning?

How should I interpret the argument of the member function?

Comment: `ThisClass**` is a `pointer-to-pointer-to-ThisClass`

Comment: No special meaning, it's a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ** a repeated round of 'pointing',

Yes, it signifies that `identifier`'s type is pointer-to-pointer-to-`ThisClass`, i.e. that is points to a `ThisClass*` object, which is itself a pointer-type object (pointing to a `ThisClass` object).

> or has an altogether different meaning?

No, no special meanings.

---

Similarly in an expression `**` signifies repeated dereferencing.

Comment: After curiosity. Does `ThisClass*` get defined implicitly as a class of its own (whereby its instances exist), or does it exist fictionally, as-if, for the purpose of description?

Comment: @XavierStuvw A pointer is an object like any other object. You must make sure that the `ThisClass**` that you pass to your function is actually pointing to a `ThisClass*` object in its lifetime, otherwise you will have a dangling pointer as usual. There is nothing implicitly happening or special about this.

Comment: @XavierStuvw And just to clarify: *object* in formal C++ language does not refer specifically to instances of classes in the OOP sense. E.g. every non-reference variable, even with fundamental type such as `int x;` is an *object* in the formal sense that I mean here. So `ThisClass* ptr;` would declare a variable (and thus introduce an *object*) of type `ThisClass*`, which is a pointer type, not a class type.

Comment: Thanks. Having highlighted the usage of the word _object_ in the C++ context -- hence telling pointer types from class types -- is particularly useful. You may want to bring this explanation in the answer for greater visibility.